# Gulp is compiling to css with bad prefixes?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

When i compile my sass to css, the css file is ok, but something is wrong with some css elements. Gulp or something is adding some non-brain prefixes.

( Even if i write the arrow-up by hand, the problem is still here )

( I have only 1 plugin in gulp = BroserSync. I tried to compile it without the plugin and it's still the same )

An example here:

Sass code :

```
&:before
    position: absolute
    bottom: 100%
    left: 0
    content: ''
    height: 0
    width: 0
    +arrow-up(5px, $green-gray)
```

Mixin arrow-up :

```
=arrow-up($px, $color)
    border-bottom:  $px solid $color
    border-right:   $px solid transparent
    border-left:    $px solid transparent
    border-top:     $px solid transparent
```

Compiled css :

```
  .detail-comment-tools li span:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #a1b0aa;
      border-bottom-border-right: 5px solid transparent;
      border-bottom-border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      border-bottom-border-top: 5px solid transparent; }
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src('public/sass/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost/creandosu/public"
    });

    gulp.watch('public/sass/*.sass', ['styles']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve']);
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code.  It is impossible to copy/paste them into our editors and compile it for ourselves.

Comment: Edited, thank you for the info.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c79300484c92774b910084479f360982

Comment: So the problem should be somewhere in gulp as i expected ?

Comment: You could have tested it yourself by just running Sass by itself.  Also, you haven't actually provided the actual code that reproduces your output.

Comment: I added the gulpfile.js

Comment: @cimmanon was talking about the output generated by your gulpfile after running if there is no error.

Comment: @SebastianManuelli have you tried debugging any of this yourself?  Did you try removing all of your plugins?  Did you try compiling Sass without Gulp?  These are things you should have done *before* asking this question.

Comment: Carlos Bensant - yes there are no errors. 
Cimmanon - yes i've tried

Comment: What does "there is no error" mean?  And more importantly, what do you want *us* to do about it?  This question appears to be highly unproductive, since the only people capable of resolving a problem with Gulp are the maintainers of Gulp.

Comment: @cimmanon -  I was just searching for any help, maybe if someone had this problem and know how to fix it, because it's very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting some unexpected behavior due to missing some semicolons.

Perhaps

```
=arrow-up($px, $color)
  border-bottom:  $px solid $color
  border-right:   $px solid transparent
  border-left:    $px solid transparent
  border-top:     $px solid transparent
```

should be

```
=arrow-up($px, $color)
  border-bottom:  $px solid $color;
  border-right:   $px solid transparent;
  border-left:    $px solid transparent;
  border-top:     $px solid transparent;
```